# Ask how to, and/or for hire

Tags: discussion

I have a question regarding re-writing and/or hacking an epson printer driver. Likely the answer(s) will also be beyond my ability to implement. Is it okay to ask for people to contact me re: paying someone to make the change?  If not, where can I ask to catch the attention of SO people?

Comment: See http://www.odesk.com/home

Answer (score 10):

No, it's not really acceptable to have people contact you to be hired for a project. You're more than willing to contact answerers directly if they have their contact information listed, but actively soliciting help in a question is bad form and generally frowned upon.

If you're looking to hire good developers to help you on a project, you can try posting a job to the [Stack Overflow Job Boards](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/billing/checkoutnew) on [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: So this can be rephrased as *"there isn't a good place [in the SO family] to ask for paid help"*. What about elsewhere?

Comment: @matt: I believe that would be http://careers.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Matt & @matt careers is for long-term jobs, not single small projects. I think it is safe to say there is no good place for this at the moment

Comment: @Pekka: I'm not sure about that. When editing your CV, one of the options under "What type of work are you seeking?" is "Temporary contract."

Comment: @Matt fair enough, but the $350 fee for the employer *is* pretty massive for a single project. Not unthinkable for bigger jobs, but still a sizeable chunk.

Comment: @Pekka, @Matt Ball - yeah temp contract is one of the options for people filing their CVs, but the someone wanting to search the CV's has to pony up $500 for the privilige. I understand and agree with the reason for that, but it does mean that for the kind of project I have on my bench right now I have no (quality) options.

Comment: Careers/Jobs did shutdown on April 1st (no joke)

Answer (score 1):

> where can I ask to catch the attention
>   of SO people?

[SO Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) would be a great place to look, it will contain "SO people" who actually are looking for work. Even if they are looking for full-time work, they might be interested in a small side job.

Comment: Thanks. Careers is the right idea, but this job isn't big enough for the buy-in price. I guess there's still a niche to fill.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Elance](http://www.elance.com/), a website that is geared towards small-to-medium web-sourced contract work.  It doesn't have any specific ties to SO, but I've seen it mentioned a couple of times on here.

Comment: thanks. The search doesn't work very well, returning results only vaguely related, but the process for posting a small job is fairly smooth and painless. We'll see if anything comes of it.